# Redirect Cms Page using htaccess in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am working on laravel project. I have created a cms table and had crud for CMS pages. In the front end, I've cms pages in the footer where I've to redirect the user using htaccess. I've created a view file for showing the cms content and I am fetching details on the basis of page id. For example page id 1 is for aboutus. If I am giving the link as pages/1 then it is showing the page content properly. I want to show the URL as aboutus instead of pages/1.

I have the following code in my **public/htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^aboutus/$ /pages/1

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

WIen i am redirecting user to **/aboutus** it is showing **404 error**. Please let me know how to redirect the user to /aboutus.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Udhav do you have any answer about this bro? Please do let me know. I am still waiting for the solution

Comment: Sorry i have no solution about this question, I am trying to find out the solution